# I have installed Tensorflow but I can not import it in Python: ImportError: cannot import name 'descriptor' from 'google.protobuf' (unknown location)

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

I have installed Tensorflow successfully in my Windows 10 Notebook:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install tensorflow-gpu
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: gast==0.2.2 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.8 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-estimator<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: google-pasta>=0.1.6 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.33.6)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.6.1 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: astor>=0.6.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.8->tensorflow-gpu) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.6.1->tensorflow-gpu) (41.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow-gpu) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\alienware\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->tensorflow-gpu) (3.1.1)
```

However, when I try to import it in Python I get an error message:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda activate base

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
>>>
```

When I run `conda list` I get:

[image]

### Update

I followed Rachayita's advise below but I have installed Tensorflow 1.4 and I want tensorflow-gpu 2.0

From my base Anaconda environment I uninstalled tensorflow-gpu 2.0 which was installed and then re-installed it with pip following the official tensorflow documentation.

When I tried to import it in python I got the following error message:

```
(base) C:\Users\Alienware>python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2019-10-22 23:35:53.390099: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: cannot import name 'descriptor' from 'google.protobuf' (unknown location)
```

Comment: try `conda list` to see if it exists

Comment: Did you install `tensorflow` inside or outside the same virtual environment?

Comment: @Rachayita : Inside the only virtual environment there is: base.  Please see my updated post.

Comment: And did you install it from the Anaconda prompt?

Comment: have you a file with name tensorflow,py in the same root?

Comment: @Giovani: Which root?  I have two drives: C: and D:.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: @Giovani: No there is no tensorflow.py in C:\WINDOW\System32

Comment: This question (and its answers/comments) appears to be descending into guesswork, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. Readers need a [mcve] to be able to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install it with Anaconda by running the following commands on the Anaconda prompt:

```
> conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu
> conda activate tf-gpu
```

Here is the complete documentation - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

Comment: Thank you Rachayita, I followed your advice but now I can not launch Jupyter Notebook from the new environment for some reason.  See my updated post.

Comment: Could you install Jupyter with conda too? You can use `conda install jupyter`. If you need to uninstall it first, do that.

Comment: Hey! Use the following steps: 1) Uninstall pyzmq by `conda uninstall pyzmq` 2) Reinstall pyzmq by `conda install pyzmq` 3) Reinstall Jupyter by `conda install jupyter`

Comment: @ Rachayita: I installed Jupyter Notebook with conda and runs fine.  But I found out that the tensorflow version installed by conda is the 1.4 and I want 2.0. This was why I used pip in the first place.  Now what I do?

Comment: When you installed it with pip, was `pip` installed with conda, as in did you do `conda install pip` and then `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: Yes.  Installed it with pip after I run conda install pip.

Comment: Try the instructions here? https://medium.com/@shaolinkhoa/install-tensorflow-gpu-2-0-alpha-on-anaconda-for-windows-10-ubuntu-ced099010b21

Comment: Yes at last it worked!  Thank you Rachayita!  I upvoted your reply too!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run "pip install tensorflow-gpu" after "conda activate base"?

If not then that is what you need to do since tensorflow will not be installed in your virtual enviroment "base".

Comment: Yes, please see updated post.

Comment: I did the same on my setup without errors, but I have tensorflow 1.12. Have you tried "from __future__ import absolute_import" first then "import tensorflow"?

Comment: I am getting an error: ImportError: cannot import name 'absolute_import' from 'future'

Comment: You can try what they did here. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181758/why-is-from-future-import-absolute-import-throwing-importerror-cannot-impor>

Answer (score 0):

You have to install tensorflow using pip install tensorflow and not tensorflow-gpu

Comment: I want to run tensorflow on gpu and according to tensorflow documentation I have run the proper command: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: Have you got a "NVIDIA® GPU card with CUDA® Compute Capability 3.5 or higher" because on the documentation it says that thats the only one supported